# Erro logout servlet cookie

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Olá.
Estou com erro na linha:

`Cookie cookie = new Cookies(req.getCookies().getUsuarioLogado();`

O método/classe completo é esse:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/logout")
public class Logout extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //String getCookies = req.getParameter(getCookies);
    //String getUsuarioLogado = req.getParameter(getUsuarioLogado);

    Cookie cookie = new Cookies(req.getCookies().getUsuarioLogado();
    if(cookie!=null) {
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        resp.addCookie(cookie);
    }
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    writer.println("<html><body>Logout efetuado</body></html>");
    }
}
```

Não estou conseguindo solucionar o erro. Alguém sabe?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui arrumar, meu código atual está assim:

```
public class Logout extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //String getCookies = req.getParameter(getCookies);
    //String getUsuarioLogado = req.getParameter(getUsuarioLogado);

    Cookie cookie = new Cookies(req.getCookies()).getUsuarioLogado();
    if(cookie!=null) {
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        resp.addCookie(cookie);
    }
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    writer.println("<html><body>Logout efetuado</body></html>");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Oi!
Para você gerar um cookie é da seguinte forma:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("nome_cookie", "valor_cookie");
```

O método getCookies retorna a lista dos cookies. O mesmo não possui o método getUsuarioLogado.

Para você recuperar o cookie que você deseja, você deve iterar a lista retornada pelo getCookies.

exemplo:

```
Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
for(Cookie cookie : cookies) {
  if(cookie.getName().equals("nome_que_você_deseja") {
     // faz o que você precisa
    break;
  }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Mas tipo quero saber o porque está com erro na linha que citei.

Comment: @ThiagoFerreira

Qual foi o erro que deu?
Você não apontou.
Tipo, creio que seja a tentativa de chamada do método:

Cookie cookie = new Cookies(req.getCookies().getUsuarioLogado();
sem falar que esta faltando fechar o parenteses no fim da linha.

Mas de qualquer forma você não pode fazer eq.getCookies().getUsuarioLogado() pois getCookies retorna um array de Cookies e não um objeto que possui o método getUsuarioLogado

Comment: esse erro: Cannot invoke getUsuarioLogado() on the array type Cookie[]

Comment: fechei o parênteses e continuou o erro.

Comment: Então
é como falei...
você não pode fazer getUsuarioLogado() pois um Cookie[] não tem esse método.
O jeito correto é fazer como eu coloquei na resposta, você tem que iterar o Array e fazer sua lógica para recuperar o usuario.

Comment: Eu apenas coloquei o parênteses no lugar correto e deu certo aqui.